# How to install Ubuntu on a Nokia n900

Tags: installation

I read about ubuntu for phone and want to know if I can install Ubuntu on an n900 because this one has debian I think.

Comment: The N900 has Maemo 5 OS, and not Debian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A guide has been posted to [port it](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Porting).

So if your phone support [minimum configuration](http://www.ubuntu.com/devices/tablet/partner) & CM10 build available for it, then you can port it.

Various Devs are working on porting, you can check the list from here https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices

As far as nokia, I don't think it is possible as of now.

1. Bootloader can not unlocked (most probably)
2. No android driver available. Android driver binaries are used as base.

From their official FAQ, please see

- [Can you make it run on my device xyz as well?](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/FAQ#Can_you_make_it_run_on_my_device_xyz_as_well.3F)
- [How is Ubuntu Touch connected to Android?](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/FAQ#How_is_Ubuntu_Touch_connected_to_Android.3F)
- [Does that mean that only Android Devices are able to run Ubuntu Touch?](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/FAQ#Does_that_mean_that_only_Android_Devices_are_able_to_run_Ubuntu_Touch.3F)